# "Missing Input Data" message on python request

Tags: python

I'm using this code

```
import urllib
import json
import requests

base_url = 'https://api.yomdam.com/1.0/stats/log'

headers = { "Content-type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "YOMDAM-API-KEY":"1303-M0G7-AA8D-WWDN-MM7W-XXXX"}

message ={"log_payload": {"activity": "TEST","date": 1444403649404,"Key1": "Value1","Key2": "Value2"}}

r = requests.post(base_url, headers=headers, params = json.dumps(message))
```

I keep getting

> {"message": "Missing Input Data. Required keys: [u'log_payload']"}

I've tried same request using Postman on chrome and it works, I don't know why code won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using the `data` keyword parameter to the `requests.post` call ie.:

```
r = requests.post(base_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(message))
```

This way the json ends up in the post body instead of in the url.

See my [previous answer today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33068046/2723675).

**EDIT**

as pointed out below and as verified [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) you could simplify the call to:

```
r = requests.post(base_url, headers=headers, json=message)
```

Comment: Do you really need the `json.dumps()`, I thought `requests` did that for you.

Comment: Yeah seem I really need to use json.dumps() otherwise I get a complain from the server

Comment: OK, so you need to pass to the json parameter as described [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) to have the json serialized for you.